# Exception when using YouTubePlayerFragment with FragmentActivity and ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api, android-actionbar

I am trying to implement a layout using the new [YouTube Player API for Android](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) . Currently, I have a simple layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  <fragment
      android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
      android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="Nothin"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, in my activity, I have the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener
```

I was under the impression that using a fragment in my layout, meant that I needed to use a FragmentActivity (which is from android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity). However, I am getting the following exception when I run this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

This works when I extend Activity instead of FragmentActivity. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

YouTubePlayerFragment inherits from android.app.Fragment, and you cast it somewhere to android.support.v4.app.Fragment. If you want to use this class on older API-s then use YouTubePlayerSupportFragment, otherwise fix your imports.

Comment: Thanks! I just used YouTubePlayerSupportFragment and it works!